# unable to edit tablecell in NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, checkbox, nstableview

i have a NSMutableArray filled with NSMutableDictionaries. all this data is shown in a NSTableView.

problem is when i try to edit a cell. my tableview is bound to my class with the datasource binding. and to edit a cell's value i use this code:

```
 -(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView setObjectValue:(id)object forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row{

NSMutableDictionary *i = [list objectAtIndex:row];
NSString *identifier = [tableColumn identifier];
[i setValue:object forKey:identifier];

 }
```

but its thowing an error:

```
2013-02-11 20:50:35.960 prog[424:303] Exception detected while handling key input.
2013-02-11 20:50:35.960 prog[424:303] [<__NSDictionaryI 0x105986580>     setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key filename.
2013-02-11 20:50:35.964 prog[424:303] (
```

i dont get why i am getting this `NSDictionaryI` error. i am using everywhere NSMutableDictionary even where i add the dictionary to the array. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found the problem!

when i added elements to my array i was using COPY. removing that made it work!

`[myNSMutableArray addObject: myNSMutableDictionary];`

before i was using

`[myNSMutableArray addObject:copy myNSMutableDictionary];`

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey
```

means, that you have a problem with your tableColumn identifier. Check the set identifier in the Interface Builder and/or set a breakpoint (or just do a NSLog(@"%@", tableColumn.identifier);)